# more effiecient way for this for loop in matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I have the following minimal code:

```
N=30;
P=200;
a = lpc(signal,N);
y = zeros(1, P);
y(1:N) = x(1:N);

for ii=(N+1):P      
     y(ii) = -sum(a(2:end) .* y((ii-1):-1:(ii-N)));
end
```

the for loop in `y` is not efficient, is the a way to vectorize this? maybe a matlab related function ?

EDIT: 
some more context to the question - I am trying to predict a known periodic signal efficiently using `lpc`. For `a=lpc(signal,3)` I found in matlab documentation that `y=filter([0 -a(2:end)],1,x)` would do, how do I generalize it to `lpc(signal,N)`?

Comment: Seems like some kind of convolution. What are you computing there?

Comment: This looks like a recursive filter. Check `filter`

Comment: I'm trying to extrapolate an periodic signal using a linear prediction auto-regressive model (in my code `a=lpc(x, N);` with `x` as the measured signal)

Comment: ok for a smaller lpc order (say 3), I can use `y = filter([0 -a(2:end)],1,x);` my question is about how to use filter for `lpc(x,N)`?

Answer (score 1):

I used the symbolic toolbox to print out the formula for any later `y` values. These formulas are very long and require about `(ii-N)*N` multiplications for step `ii` to calculate `y` directly. A vectorised solution would have to do all these multiplications, it will be slower.

Optimizing your loop is everything that can be done:

```
b=a(end:-1:2);
for ii=(N+1):P      
     y(ii) = -sum(b .* y((ii-N):(ii-1)));
end
```

Indexing backwards is slow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an easily feasible way, as each position in `y` depends on its precedessors. So they have to be calculated step by step.

Comment: I agree.  Because this is a recurrence relationship, you can't avoid using a `for` loop.

Comment: doesn't matlab have special optimized functions \ filters for that?

Comment: Not that I know of... But perhaps one of the other MATLAB bigs can provide you with an answer....because I don't know of any that can help you in this particular case.